# Why aren't these dependencies showing up in maven?

Tags: maven, dependencies

```
mvn dependency:tree -X
```

Shows:

```
...
[INFO] +- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws:pom:2.1.4.RELEASE:compile 
[INFO] +- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
...
```

...and yet when I look at the [pom](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/ws/spring-ws/2.1.4.RELEASE/spring-ws-2.1.4.RELEASE.pom) for `spring-ws` I see that it has dependencies that aren't shown here. What's up with that??  How can I force maven to show ALL the dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should figure out is that dependency is party of the dependency tree using below command or refer link provided

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=name_of_dependency:name_of_dependecy
```

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/filtering-the-dependency-tree.html

If it is not then it might have been excluded.

Comment: It's not excluded. I already know that people create these BOM (Bill Of Materials) POMs and that they represent a set of dependencies without any artifacts being built.  IMHO the fact that the dependencies don't show up by default is a big fat bug but  apparently the folks at Maven don't agree. My question stands. Is there a way to force maven to display them?  I'm attempting the specific technique you are mentioning now but I have no reason to expect that it will work if "mvn dependency:tree" didn't work the first time even with -X.

Comment: Tried: mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.springframework.ws:spring-ws results were the same. Will try specifically the dependencies mentioned in the BOM although this is pointless since it presumes you know them before the system has told you about them.

Comment: I have the answer to this question. 1. I've got the wrong POM link. It's been corrected. 2. I've been working these pesky BOM's (they show up as :pom: in dependency listings like the above) for so long I hadn't anticipated one that had no dependencies. :-/  This build is huge and converting it to Gradle has been an exercise in tedium.